# Debian - Stripped down Automated Install Disc

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation

I want to create a debian install disc that only installs the minimum software to get a web browser such as ice weasel to run in an x-windows environment.

**Question: How can I make an stripped down automated install disc for Debian?** The other option is to use the automated install option and script removing unneeded software after install, but that seems like the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, do you want to do an unattended install? If not, you can tell the Debian installer to install only the minimum software to get the system up, and then add stuff later. This will typically only install very basic things, and no X stuff at all.

Alternatively, you can use debconf preseeding with [FAI](http://wiki.debian.org/FAI). I'm not sure whether you can do a minimal Debian install with this, but I don't see why not. Search for "debconf preseeding fai" or "debconf preseeding".

Alternatively, the first Google hit to "custom debian installer" is http://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD, but for what you are trying to do it may be overkill.

Comment: Unattended is the correct word for the method.